React app to appendable widget using @r2wc/react-to-web-component working just for the first custom element on page
I'm trying to develop a widget from a react app using vite following this nice tutorial :
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/converting-react-app-appendable-widget-using-web-mike-rahimi-wssnf/
Ideally my widget should be instantiated multiple times on the same HTML page but with different params.
here an example of the intended html page
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="http://localhost:4173/assets/js/widget.js" type="module"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <my-widget id="1" applicationId="app1"  />
    <my-widget id="2" applicationId="app2"  />
</body>

</html>

where <my-widget> is as simple as

function App(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <h1> {applicationId}</h1>
      
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

and here is my widget.js file
import r2wc from "@r2wc/react-to-web-component";
import App from "./App";

const WebComponentWidget = r2wc(App, {
  props: {
    applicationId: "string",
  },
});

customElements.define("my-widget", WebComponentWidget);

and here my vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { resolve } from "path";
import cssInjectedByJsPlugin from "vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), cssInjectedByJsPlugin()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, "./src/main.jsx"),
        widget: "./src/Widget.js",
      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
          return assetInfo.name === "widget"
            ? "assets/js/[name].js"
            : "assets/[name].js";
        },
      },
    },
  },
  experimental: {
    renderBuiltUrl(filename) {
      return "http://localhost:4173/" + filename;
    },
  },
});

Widget works  but  is only being rendered for the first custom-element on the page:
 <my-widget id="1" applicationId="app1"  />

I guess i'm missing something but even the most basic "helloworld" component is just working for the first custom-element on the page.
